# Getting Access to 'a' in StateT

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function with `StateT` only to learn more about it.

In `f`, I'd like to access to the `Int` in the last type argument of `StateT [Int] IO Int`:

```
f :: StateT [Int] IO Int
f = state $ \xs -> update (error "I want a") xs

update :: Int -> [Int] -> (Int, [Int])      
update x []     = (x, [])
update x (y:ys) = (x+y, ys)
```

Here's how I'd like to call it:

`let x = return 55 ::  StateT [Int] IO Int`

Referencing `runStateT`:

```
*Main> :t runStateT
runStateT :: StateT s m a -> s -> m (a, s)
```

I'd expect to run it:

`runStateT (f x) [1,2,3]`

to get the following from GHCI, i.e. the `IO (Int, [Int])` gets printed:

```
(56, [2,3])
```

since the inner `a`, i.e. `55`, `+ 1`, i.e. from `[1,2,3]`, returns `(56, [2,3])`.

How can I write the above function, getting access to the `a`?

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking here. "In `f`, I'd like to access to the Int in the last type argument of `StateT [Int] IO Int`" - the last type argument is the _return type_ of the monadic computation, not something you can access from within. Could you post some code you've tried along with the error you're getting?

Comment: Maybe you meant `f :: Int -> StateT [Int] IO Int` ?

Comment: There is no "inner `a`, i.e. `55`" until you run the calculation, except for the case where you know in advance that `x` is `return something`; in which case you should just pass `something` in the first place.

Comment: It's hard to get a starting point for an answer here since `f x` is ill-typed as others have pointed out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here's what say you want:

```
>>> let x = return 55 ::  StateT [Int] IO Int
>>> runStateT (f x) [1,2,3]
(56, [2,3])
```

So let's work backwards from that.

From the use of `f`, we can infer its type -

```
f :: StateT [Int] IO Int -> StateT [Int] IO Int
```

Note the difference from your given type for `f` in the question - namely `f` is a function between values of type `StateT [Int] IO Int`, not a value of that type.

To define `f`, we need `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. This will allow us to take our input of type `StateT [Int] IO Int` and run some computation on the `Int` the input computes.

```
f x = x >>= \i -> state (splitAt 1) >>= \[j] -> return (i + j)
```

or, using do-notation:

```
f x = do
  i <- x
  [j] <- state (splitAt 1)
  return (i + j)
```

Which gives us exactly the result we want.

While this works, it's highly non-idiomatic. Rather than passing monadic values in as inputs to functions and binding them inside the function, it's far more common to define functions that take regular values and return monadic ones, using the bind operator (`>>=`) *outside*.

So it'd be far more normal to define

```
shiftAdd :: Int -> StateT [Int] IO Int
shiftAdd i = do
  [j] <- state (splitAt 1)
  return (i + j)
```

So now we can run not only

```
>>> runStateT (shiftAdd 55) [1,2,3]
(56,[2,3])
```

but also

```
>>> runStateT (shiftAdd 55 >>= shiftAdd >>= shiftAdd)
(61,[])
```

It's still not as idiomatic as it could be as:

- I made it unnecessarily partial by using `splitAt` (it'll throw an exception if the state list is empty)
- it's unnecessarily specific (doesn't use IO at all, but we can't use it with other base monads)

Fixing that up gives us:

```
shiftAdd' :: (Monad m, Num a) => a -> StateT [a] m a
shiftAdd' i = state $ \js -> case js of
  [] -> (i, [])
  j : js -> (i + j, js)
```

Which works just fine:

```
>>> runStateT (return 55 >>= shiftAdd') [1,2,3]
(56,[2,3])
>>> runStateT (return 55 >>= shiftAdd' >>= shiftAdd' >>= shiftAdd') [1,2,3]
(61,[])
>>> runStateT (return 55 >>= shiftAdd' >>= shiftAdd' >>= shiftAdd') []
(55,[])
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful, detailed answer!